# Checking if two sum of squared residuals are significantly different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, residuals

I have a system of non linear differential equations and in order to find model parameters I have fitted the model to some data using non linear least squares method and have calculated the sum of squared residuals. But for some reason I had to deviate from this best fit parameters and use slightly different values for the model. Now I want to check whether when these adjusted parameter values are used and check with data if the sum of squared errors that I obtain now is significantly different to than that of the previous one (as a way to indicate that although that I have used slightly different values form the best fit parameters it doesn't affect significantly).

So, basically I want to check if the difference of two sum of squared errors is significantly different from one another.

If $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the two sum of squared errors what type of test can I use? can I use t test and can you please explain how to construct it.

Comment: Do you care about the magnitude of the squared errors or the pattern of the square errors?

Comment: @ReneBt magnitude of the squared errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T-test works on normal data and the assumption under many fitted models is that the residual variation (error) is normally distributed. You can test this assumption using a test such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov and if it fails you can use non-parametric equivalents of the T-test (although it would probably also lead to questions about the appropriateness of your model if one assumption was normality in the residuals).

To work with a T-test you would take the magnitude of the errors as vectors for each model (not the square errors, the T-test is based on variation not variance) and compare them using a paired T-test. What this will allow you to assess is whether the differences between the models can be explained by random chance reasonably well.

However, if what you want is to demonstrate *equivalence* of the models, then you have a more stringent test to perform, a test of equivalence:
http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rdecook/stat6220/Class_notes/equivalence_testing.pdf
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5502906/